# Database Connection fails when running native docker image

Tags: docker, tomcat, datasource, native, spring-native

I have a Java 17 Spring Boot 3 app. Building with `mvn package` and then running with `mvn spring-boot:run` works fine. Now I want to build a native docker image. Building it with `mvn spring-boot:native-image -Pnative` works but when I try to run it with `docker run <name>` it fails. It seems like somehow the datasource config needs to be different than in the "normal" maven build.
What's going on here? I really appreciate your answers.

#### The error:

```
2023-07-18T09:28:42.499Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 22 ms
2023-07-18T09:28:42.506Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: registry-persistence]
2023-07-18T09:28:42.507Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-07-18T09:28:42.511Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
2023-07-18T09:28:42.511Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
        at java.sql@17.0.7/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:na]
        at java.sql@17.0.7/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:344) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:227) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:775) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:703) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:502) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:153) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:119) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:108) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]

2023-07-18T09:28:42.512Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
        at java.sql@17.0.7/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:na]
        at java.sql@17.0.7/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:344) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:227) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:775) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:703) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:502) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:153) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:119) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:108) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]

2023-07-18T09:28:42.513Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-07-18T09:28:42.513Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-07-18T09:28:42.513Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-07-18T09:28:42.514Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:147) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:60) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:244) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.1.7.Final]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

#### pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.78</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>cfg/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>logback-spring.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <!-- -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>logback-spring.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>cfg/**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>systemd/**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### Datasource Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DefaultDsConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultDs")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.tomcat")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

#### application.properties:

```
# Server port
server.port=9999
server.servlet.context-path=/REST/registry

spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true 
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

spring.datasource.tomcat.url=<url>
spring.datasource.tomcat.username=<username>
spring.datasource.tomcat.password=<password>
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.tomcat.defaultAutoCommit=false
spring.datasource.tomcat.rollbackOnReturn=true  
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true      
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false                   
spring.datasource.tomcat.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Let me know if you need any more info.